# Convert A nested else if statement in to a switch statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following endpoint with a nested (if) else if statement

```
@Patch("/games/:id")
  @HttpCode(200)
  async updateGame(@Param("id") id: number, @Body() update: Partial<Game>) {

    const updatedGame = await Game.findOne(id);
    if (!updatedGame) {
      throw new NotFoundError("HTTP 404 Not Found: No Games Here");
    } else if (update.color && !validColor(update.color)) {
      throw new BadRequestError("HTTP 400 Bad Request: No Such Color");
    } else if (
      update.board !== undefined &&
      moves(update.board, updatedGame.board) > 1
    ) {
      throw new BadRequestError(
        "HTTP 400 Bad Request:  Only one move allowed. Wait your turn"
      );
    } else {
      console.log("Game has been updated");
      return Game.merge(updatedGame, update).save();
    }
  }
```

And I would like to convert it to a switch statement 
 for readability 
I've tried several attempts 
but somehow the values of the constant variables aren't being read.

the following is my switch statement attempt to replace the else if list

```
switch(updatedGame){
  case (!updatedGame):
  throw new NotFoundError("HTTP 404 Not Found: No Games Here")
  case(update.color && !validColor(update.color)):
  throw new BadRequestError("HTTP 400 Bad Request: No Such Color")
  case(update.board !== undefined && moves(update.board, updatedGame.board) > 1):
  throw new BadRequestError("HTTP 400 Bad Request:  Only one move allowed. Wait your turn")
  default : console.log("Game has been updated");
   Game.merge(updatedGame, update).save();


}
```

the if else if list work as it should 
but the switch statement gives errors

Comment: btw no `else` needed after throwing an exception ...

Comment: Why do you really need to change? ...and of course it errors, as the argument in your `switch` is what the `case` evaluates, and how can it with e.g. ´case(update.color && !validColor(update.color))´ when neither is related to `updateGame`?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense as a switch, they're not all taking the same result in the conditional.

Comment: @NinaScholz If I don't then the values provided aren't being updated in the database Game.merge(updatedGame, update).save

Comment: @LGSon, 
mainly for readability. 
I find switch statements very readable 
but I suck at writing them.

Comment: Well, in your case you can't use it properly because of how the `if` statements doesn't evaluate the same variable

Comment: taking a switch statement need values which are strictly compared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For better readability, you could omit the else parts, because a thrown exception, which is not caught inside of the function ends the function.

```
if (!updatedGame) {
    throw new NotFoundError("HTTP 404 Not Found: No Games Here");
}
if (update.color && !validColor(update.color)) {
    throw new BadRequestError("HTTP 400 Bad Request: No Such Color");
}
if (update.board !== undefined && moves(update.board, updatedGame.board) > 1) {
    throw new BadRequestError("HTTP 400 Bad Request:  Only one move allowed. Wait your turn");
}
console.log("Game has been updated");
return Game.merge(updatedGame, update).save();
```

Comment: How does this improve readability? Please explain. Code given with *if..else* in question is more readable then this.

Comment: it is the early exit paradigm with single `if`. after an exit by exception or simply a return statement, nothing more happens.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense!
I somehow figured a switch statement would be cleaner.
I guess that wouldn't be best practice

Your code makes more sense and looks a lot cleaner!
Thanks!